What is the quantum map that describes a measurement where the measurement outcome is known?
My question is the other case of this question.
Suppose I do a measurement in the $Z$ basis with outcomes $\lambda_0, \lambda_1$ but I don't record the outcome. In this case, I can describe what happened with a quantum channel $\mathcal{E}$. It has Kraus operators $\{\langle 0\vert \otimes \vert \lambda_0\rangle, \langle 1\vert \otimes \vert \lambda_1\rangle \}$. Acting on a state $\rho$, I get
$$\mathcal{E}(\rho) = \langle 0\vert \rho \vert 0\rangle \otimes \vert \lambda_0\rangle\langle \lambda_0\vert + \langle 1\vert \rho \vert 1\rangle \otimes \vert \lambda_1\rangle\langle \lambda_1\vert$$
What if I do record the outcome? In this case, how do I describe the map? It has to take an input $\rho$ and give me an output $\vert 0\rangle\langle 0\vert$ if I see $\lambda_0$ and $\vert 1\rangle\langle 1\vert$ if I see $\lambda_1$

It is not a map, because it's neither deterministic nor linear. There is no better description than just saying that you get this and this state if you observe this and this outcome.
Note that the $\mathcal E$ is doing the opposite of what you want: it produces state $|\lambda_i\rangle$ if you observe result $i$.

If you know the outcome, you could still model it as a replacement channel though. But that probably isn't what the OP is looking for

@TristanNemoz I am happy to view it as a replacement channel conditioned on the observed outcome. Precisely, how should one write that?

@Jorge if you replace your state with another state $\sigma$, then the map is $\mathcal{E}(\rho)=\mathrm{tr}(\rho)\sigma$

@TristanNemoz I understand, but in this case, isn't the replacement state $\sigma$ conditioned on the measurement outcome? Can one include that conditioning in the description of the channel or does it fail due to the non-determinism and non-linearity? Thanks!

@Jorge Yes it is, this is just the general representation of the replacement channel. If you know that you measured $0$ for instance, you can describe the operation you performed as $\rho\mapsto\mathrm{tr}(\rho)|0\rangle!\langle0|$. Fundamentally, this is what you did: you took a state $\rho$ and you transformed it into the other state. Another way of writing it is, if you get the measurement outcome $x$, then the quantum channel you applied is $\rho\mapsto\mathrm{tr}(\rho)|x\rangle!\langle x|$

Thank you both for answers and comments. I asked a follow-up question here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/39274/heisenberg-picture-for-a-quantum-measurement-operation-with-known-outcome
