Heisenberg picture for a quantum measurement where the outcome is recorded
I asked a related question here. From the answer by Mateus, we see that one cannot describe a quantum measurement (where the measurement outcome is recorded) as a quantum map. That is because the measurement operation is nondeterministic.
For any observable $A$ and quantum channel $\Phi$ acting on state $\rho$, we have that
$$\text{Tr}(A\Phi(\rho)) = \text{Tr}(\Phi^\star(A)\rho)$$
where $\Phi^\star$ is the adjoint map. The second viewpoint is the Heisenberg picture where the state never evolves but the operators do.
Now, I want to take a state, measure it with the outcome recorded and then work with the post-measurement state. Let's start with $\rho$ and obtain a post-measurement state $M(\rho)$. I now measure it again with respect to an observable $A$. This gives me $\text{Tr}(A M(\rho))$ in the Schrodinger picture. But since $M(\cdot)$ is not a quantum channel, I don't know how to define its adjoint.
What is the Heisenberg-picture formalism for measurements?

Note that a "post-measurement" $M(\rho)$ cannot be a channel, because the function sending $\rho$ to any of the states left over after a measurement is not linear. And if $M$ is not linear, its adjoint is not defined (at least not in the standard way).
A better way to model a measurement where you have a post-measurement outcome and record the outcomes is to use a quantum instrument, which is a channel of the form
$$\Phi(\rho) = \sum_a |a\rangle\!\langle a|\otimes \Phi_a(\rho)$$
with $\Phi_a$ CP and such that $\sum_a \operatorname{tr}(\Phi_a(X))=\operatorname{tr}(X)$.
The post-measurement outcomes are in this language the states $\rho_a$ given by
$$\rho_a = \frac{\Phi_a(\rho)}{\operatorname{tr}(\Phi_a(\rho))}.$$
The adjoint of $\Phi$ is also defined just fine and it characterised by
$$\Phi^\dagger(A\otimes B) = \sum_a \langle a|A|a\rangle \Phi_a^\dagger(B).$$
